# CircleCI Approval Step Conditional on Terraform Plan

Tags: terraform, circleci

I'm trying to create a job in CircleCI that will automatically go through or not depending on the result of a command.

- If there is a zero exit code from `terraform plan` then there are no changes, and I'd like the job to complete and move automatically on to the next step.
- If there are any changes, the command will return a nonzero exit code and I want CircleCI to ask for approval before proceeding to the next step.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have the following which seems to correctly branch depending the result of the plan (and the exit codes), but I'm not sure how to halt things, or if that's even possible on CircleCI.

```
SomeJob: 
  steps:
    - run:
        name: Plan Terraform
        command: |
          cd ./bin
          planresult=$(terraform plan)
          if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
            exit 2
          else
            exit 0
          fi
    - when:
        condition: on_fail
        steps:
          - run:
            # SOME APPROVAL STEP HERE
    - run:
         # This is the step that needs to be automated 
         # or not depending on the last one
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use an Approval step with CircleCI 2.0's Workflows feature. However, it doesn't seem like approvals are conditionally skippable based on job success yet: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/conditionally-skip-approval-step-in-workflow/14687

Comment: https://ideas.circleci.com/ideas/CCI-I-605